# Matlab sine curve fitting with linear increase

Tags: python, matlab, curve-fitting

I have multiple sets of data, each of which have a roughly sinusoidal shape. I have attached a photo of one such data [Roughly sinusoidal data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMwkw.png)

I want to fit an equation of the form y = Asin(kx+b)+mx+c. Basically the data is a sine wave with a linear increase. Is there any simple way of doing this, preferably without toolboxes as I have about 20 of these data to sort through?

Thank you.

I am using matlab, however I am open to python too :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to use regression in your function to fit the data.

One way to do this is to apply Non-linear least squares to find the parameters that minimize the square error for your function.

Take a look at the matlab function lsqcurvefit (http://es.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html)